# Python: Curses not showing printed text untill getkey() is called

Tags: python, python-curses

I have a python code that prints to the screen some text. But if i omit the `stdsrc.getkey()` function nothing prints to the screen.

```
import curses

def write(stdscr):

    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()

    stdscr.addstr("this is a test string")
    stdscr.refresh()

def main():
    curses.wrapper(write)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the above code does not show any thing on the screen but if i modify it as shown below it prints the `"this is a test string"` to the terminal

```
import curses

def write(stdscr):

    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()

    stdscr.addstr("this is a test string")
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

def main():
    curses.wrapper(write)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The problem you have is due to curses buffering the output before printing them. When you do `getkey()` or simply `input()` it'll spit out whatever it has in the buffer. Look for a way to force out the buffer. `sys.stdout.flush()` did not work.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun your solution `sys.stdout.flush()` didn't work however you are correct with your explanation. Curses creates an object and write to it, when it exist it destroys that object leaving no record of the writing: so the question now is how to force out the buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `curses.wrapper` which resets the terminal window once `write` exits. Without `getkey` it exists very quickly, the window is reset and you see nothing. `getkey` causes `write` to wait for a key and so you have time to see the change in the window. If you put `time.sleep(5)` instead of `getkey` you will have a similar effect. If you don't use `wrapper`, but call `write` directly, you will also see a change to the window.